# How can I get the `const` modifier of a CFFI function in Python?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I am writing a Python wrapper for generated C code, which contains functions that use pointer arguments as outputs. I want to introspect those functions, generated using CFFI, to determine if they are input our output arguments. The input arguments are marked `const`, but it seems CFFI discards this information.

Consider the following example

```
from cffi import FFI
ffibuilder = FFI()

ffibuilder.set_source("_example",
   r"""
        int add(const int a, const int b) {
            return a+b;
        }
    """)

ffibuilder.cdef("""
        int add(const int a, const int b);
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
    import _example
    ff = _example.lib.add
    ff_t = _example.ffi.typeof(ff)
    print(ff_t)
```

Which prints `<ctype 'int(*)(int, int)'>`, while the inputs are defined `const` in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, not possible.  This info is discarded already when translating the parsed code to CFFI's internal ctype.

Look at the `pycparser` module (which is the one that CFFI uses internally); it transforms C source code into a parse tree.  From there you can get all this info again more directly.

Comment: Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It's not CFFI's goal.

Comment: Why does CFFI have an incomplete type representation? Does that not cause problems? Or is CFFI only concerned with the size and meaning of the type, rather than its semantics? I recall some portion of the docs that mention there is nothing that stops you from trying to write to a static char array, I imagine having a proper representation of the type would solve that.

Comment: CFFI's approach is not to use types to address any particular problem (just like it was not the philosophy behind Python either).  CFFI only uses types because you can't call foreign functions in C without them.  Now if, in your case, the C library you're calling exposes types from which you can derive some higher-level information, then yes, of course you can build on top of that.  In your case it's the ``const``; in other cases it's preformatted comments, written before or after; etc.  There is no single answer that would fit inside CFFI.  In your case all you need is ``pycparser``.